# SSRS Report and image issue in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, razor

I am working on MVC Razor project in which I have to display a report from SSRS in a particular section , as there are no specific control for report viewing in MVC.I tried to use HtmlFragment and turning off the javascript in the parameter.
The report is coming on my web page but image is broken and when i see the viewsource of the page the image tag src point to the report server url which we don't want because we don,t want enduser to get link to report server.Is there any way to get all the images used on the report separately.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

In our MVC project, we ended up adding an aspx page with only the report viewer control and then displayed that report aspx page on our MVC rendered pages using an iframe.